# How to listen to ValueChangedEvents fired by widgets on Editor<?> in GWT?

Tags: java, events, gwt

My Editor consists of several TextBoxes, CheckBoxes, etc. What is the proper way of listening on the editor itself for ValueChangeEvents triggered by its widgets?

I'm trying to make sense of [Developer's Guide - Editors](https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideUiEditors) but to no avail.

Answer (score 2):

(Expanded discussion from a G+ post)

A few thoughts you might consider:

- Placebo save buttons are not a terrible idea. In a dialog box, 'save' often means 'save and close', which means that it is likely next to a 'cancel and close' type button - if no changes have been made, the effect will be the same. Only the code needs to know there is a difference in the case of no changes. In a document, 'save' is just a way to flush any recent changes back, and again, the code behind the button can ignore it. Allowing users to instruct the software to save more than is necessary is probably not a bad thing, that said...
- The Editor framework is built to allow visitors walk over the tree of editors that the driver knows about. This would enable you to build a visitor that can ask each editor in the tree if it implements HasValueChangeHandlers, and if so, add a handler. But...
- ValueChangeEvents go off when the widget logically has undergone a change and has a new value. These changes almost always only occur once the user has blurred out of the field - if the cursor is still in the only TextBox that the user has modified, and the user hovers over the save button, it will still be blurred, since no ValueChangeEvent has occurred. You would need to either wait for them to leave the field, or poll the active field to see if it has a new value, or ask the driver if it is dirty. Note that not all widgets will poll well - some don't have values available while still focused (any CellWidget for example), and others don't understand isDirty() (like HasDataEditor).

Example editor visitor to look for `HasValueChangeHandlers`:

```
driver.accept(new EditorVisitor(){
  @Override
  public <T> void endVisit(EditorContext<T> ctx) {
    Editor<T> ed = ctx.getEditor();
    if (ed instanceof HasValueChangeHandlers) {
      @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
      HasValueChangeHandlers<T> hasHandlers = (HasValueChangeHandlers<T>) ed;
      hasHandlers.addValueChangeHandler(new ValueChangeHandler<T>() {
        @Override
        public void onValueChange(ValueChangeEvent<T> event) {
          // TODO update button
          // consider comparing event.getValue() with ctx.getFromModel()
          // though that requires seeing which editors have changes...
        }
      });
    }
  }
});
```

Example polling for changes:

```
Timer t = new Timer(){
  @Override
  public void run() {
    boolean hasChanges = driver.isDirty();
    // TODO update button with the hasChanges value
  }
};
t.schedule(500);
// Don't forget to cancel() this when done, both on save and cancel!
```